# Search Query with Pagination

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-5.4

When I run a search with constraints and get more than the set paginate amount, if I change the pages the search query is lost and my default page 2 is shown rather than the 2nd page of results for

Comment: can you post how you display the pagination in your html here?

Comment: {!!$batsmen->links()!!}

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

I believe your primary issue is that if either of `!empty($name)` or `!empty($cat)` are true, you run `get()` on the query and it returns a collection. You can't use this pagination method on a collection, it can only be run via query builder or Eloquent.

You should simply be able to remove `->get()` from those two conditions to ensure that if either of them are true they don't convert your Eloquent object into a collection.

---

If you look at the documentation for pagination [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination) you can see the following warning:

> Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot
>   be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with
>   a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database
>   and create a paginator manually.

You're using `groupBy('batsmen.id')` which is going to cause issues, I'd also be wondering why you're trying to group by an inherently unique column?

Comment: Thats not the problem, the problem is that when a search is run and the paginate of 8 is passed, if i click onto page two it goes to the default search query rather than the 2nd page of the paginate on that constraint search